# Badly Stuck data is no getting updated in my database

Tags: sql

```
try{
            
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
           
 Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/buldingmaintainancesoftware","root","");

    PreparedStatement ps=conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE ownerdetails SET name=?,contact=?,email=?,due=?,paid=?,total=?,Date=? where RoomNo=?");
            ps.setString(1, RoomNo.getText());
            ps.setString(2, Name.getText());
            ps.setString(3, Contact.getText());
            ps.setString(4, Email.getText());
            ps.setInt(5,Integer.parseInt(Due.getText()));
            ps.setInt(6,Integer.parseInt(Paid.getText()));
            ps.setInt(7, Integer.parseInt(Total.getText()));
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
                String dob1=sdf.format(date1.getDate());
                ps.setString(8,dob1);
            ps.executeUpdate();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data Saved SucessFully");
            RoomNo.setText("");
            Name.setText("");
            Contact.setText("");
            Email.setText("");
            Due.setText("");
            Paid.setText("");
            Total.setText("");
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException | NumberFormatException | HeadlessException e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
        }
```

Comment: What's the context? What are you trying to do? Do you get any errors - and if so: what are those errors?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.